# What is this nuance of こればかり and how it's different from just これは or これだけ?

Tags: sentence, subjects, particle-ばかり

そんなのおかしいよっ!

おかしい?

そうかもしれない

こればかりはふたりとも驚くかも

The character realized he likes both the girls he has been hanging around recently and so he's monologuing in his mind that it's weird.

My understanding is akin to

> This is weird

> Weird?

> That may be so

> This will shock the two of them

Answer (score 2):

This type of ばかり is indeed like だけ. So こればかりは驚くかも, これだけは驚くかも and さすがにこれは驚くかも mean roughly the same thing, "(They won't be surprised by most things, but indeed,) they may be surprised by (at least) *this* one".

Still, こればかりは sounds a little more natural than これだけは in a situation like this. こればかりは is almost a set phrase used (usually at the beginning of a sentence) to express that the said situation is exceptional and beyond someone's control.

- こればかりは仕方がありませんよ。
  There's nothing we can do in this particular case.
- こればかりは彼が可哀想だ。
  You really have to feel sorry for him in this case.
- こればかりは口が裂けても言えないんだ。
  When it comes to this matter, my lips are sealed.
- こればかりは…ねえ。
  Well, you know, this is...exceptional.